# Closing a while conditonally in diffrent places

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a single php file I can use to display the content for the index or a page in wordpress. This question is not wordpress specific though.

I have a 'while' which needs to be closed in two different places depending on whether the index or a page is being displayed. I am trying to close the 'while' with an 'if'

```
if (is_home()) { endwhile; }
// otherphp
if (is_page()) { endwhile; }
```

This is not working though. The full code is below:

```
<section id="main">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php if (is_home()) : ?> <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> <?php elseif (is_page()) : ?> <article class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> <?php else : NULL; endif; ?>
    <div class="entry">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  </article>
  <?php if (is_home()) { endwhile; } ?> <!-- ENDWHILE MUST BE HERE ON INDEX PAGE -->
  <?php if (is_home()) : get_template_part('nav','default'); elseif (is_page()) : NULL; else : NULL; endif; ?>
  <?php if (is_page()) { endwhile; } ?> <!-- ENDWHILE MUST BE HERE ON ALL OTHER PAGES -->
  <?php endif; ?>
</section>
```

I realise this code is somewhat inefficient and messy but at the moment I am not concentrating on efficiency. I am simply trying to make it work.

How can I conditionally end the 'while'?

Comment: I would _strongly_ suggest re-thinking this approach. This looks like an absolute nightmare to maintain. Think of coming back to work on this file in six months and trying to figure out how to modify this so that you don't break anything.

Comment: it's worse it's syntactically incorrect.. and will not work as presented, and the fact that you are presenting it shows that you need to read up on basic programming ... so i *strongly* suggest that you go read up on it http://www.programmingvideotutorials.com/php/php-loops

Comment: I know it looks like a nightmare..... not the point.... I will clean up the mess later. I am just stuck on how to end a loop conditionally. This is not my code I am editing somebody elses codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a normal condition inside a normal `while`:

```
while (/* something */) :

    // same for all

    if (/* is home */) {
        // do something only for home
    }
endwhile;
```

Comment: hmmm but I want to end the while using an if statement.... not do something inside the while...

Comment: @Nick You cannot conditionally end a while, it's just not possible.